# Limit number of rows in each column for a Datalist

Tags: asp.net

Is there a way to have five columns in an asp.net data list and to only display 5 rows per column. So it would result in this format

```
1  6
2  7
3  8
4  9
5  10
```

I've set the repeat direction to 'vertical' already and set repeat columns to 5 but it's showing 8 per column for 5 columns.

Comment: How many items do you have to display (seems like 40) ? The only way I see to restrict the number of items per line is to set the number of columns to nbitems/nbmaxperline 40/5 => 8 columns in your case (you can also restrict the number of items to 25)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get 5 rows and 5 columns, then your DataSource needs to contain 25 items:

### HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:DataList ID="myDataList" runat="server" 
            RepeatColumns="5" 
            CellPadding="10" 
            ForeColor="#333333" 
            RepeatLayout="Table" 
            ShowFooter="False" 
            ShowHeader="False">
            <AlternatingItemStyle BackColor="White" />
            <ItemStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" 
                Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="myLabel" runat="server" 
                    Text="<%# Container.DataItem.ToString() %>" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:DataList>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### C# CodeBehind:

```c#
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class test7 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<int> myList = new List<int>();

        for(int i=1; i<26; i++) {
            myList.Add(i);
        }

        myDataList.DataSource = myList;
        myDataList.DataBind();
    }
}
```

### Output:

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't paging show it in another page though not in another column?

Comment: I edited my answer and added an example.  If you have 20 results, you would have 4 rows b/c 20 divided by 5 columns is 4.  If you have 40 rows, you would have 8 rows b/c 40 divided by 5 columns is 8.

Comment: 40 results* (not 40 rows, sorry)

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways you can do this by database query

```
select Top 5 Id,Name from table;
```

Comment: this would only give me 5 records in on column.